# Kotlin class operation on its KProperties

Tags: kotlin, reflection

I have a big Kotlin object and need to do some operations on specific properties.
Here is a small example for demo:

```
class ObjectForAnalysis {
  var id: Int = 0
  lateinit var successful: SUCCESSFUL
  var job1: Job? = null
  var job2: Job? = null
  var job3: Job? = null
}
```

Imagine that I have multiple instances of the object above and that I need to do the following operation on the properties of type Job.

```
job !=null && job.computeSquare() < 1000
```

How could I achieve that ?

Comment: Unless you want to put the `job` objects inside a list, then you'll have to use reflection in order to get those params and then you can apply your predicate. Reflection should be avoided usually, unless you are building a framework of sorts. You could also maybe create an extension function for `Job?` that applies that predicate to make it shorter, but you'll still have to call it for every param.

Comment: Could  you show an example of your extension funciton with reflection ?

Comment: `fun Job?.notNullAndSquareUnderThousand() = this != null && this.computeSquare() < 1000)` Or you could give the 1_000 as a param, `fun Job?.notNullAndSquareUnderX(x: Int) = this != null && this.computeSquare() < x`. You call this like this `job.notNullAndSquareUnderThousand()` .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import kotlin.reflect.full.memberProperties

class Job(private var i: Int) {
  fun getI(): Int = i
}

class ObjectForAnalysis {
  var id: Int = 0
  var job1: Job? = null
  var job2: Job? = null
  var job3: Job? = null
}

val list = listOf(
  ObjectForAnalysis().also { it.id = 1; it.job1 = Job(2) },
  ObjectForAnalysis().also { it.id = 2; it.job1 = Job(4); it.job2 = Job(3); it.job3 = Job(9) },
  ObjectForAnalysis().also { it.id = 3; it.job1 = Job(12); it.job2 = Job(15) },
  ObjectForAnalysis().also { it.id = 4 },
)

val properties = ObjectForAnalysis::class.memberProperties.filter { it.name.startsWith("job") }

val result = list
  .filter { ofa ->
    properties
      .map { kProperty1 ->
        (kProperty1.get(ofa) as Job?)?.let { job: Job -> job.getI() < 10 }
      }
      .all { it != null && it == true }   // all i need to be < 10
      // .any { it != null && it == true }   // at least one i needs to be < 10
  }

println("result:")
result.forEach {
  println("id: ${it.id}, ints: ${it.job1?.getI()}, ${it.job2?.getI()}, ${it.job3?.getI()}")
}

println("excluded:")
list.minus(result).forEach {
  println("id: ${it.id}, ints: ${it.job1?.getI()}, ${it.job2?.getI()}, ${it.job3?.getI()}")
}
```

Output for *.all { it != null && it == true }*:

```
result:
id: 2, ints: 4, 3, 9

excluded:
id: 1, ints: 2, null, null
id: 3, ints: 12, 15, null
id: 4, ints: null, null, null
```

Output for *.any { it != null && it == true }*:

```
result:
id: 1, ints: 2, null, null
id: 2, ints: 4, 3, 9

excluded:
id: 3, ints: 12, 15, null
id: 4, ints: null, null, null
```

Comment: I think that is a great explanation!!  I see the only solution for it is to use 
val properties = ObjectForAnalysis::class.memberProperties.filter { it.name.startsWith("job") } Right ?